# Struggling to get the Dictionary passed with NSNotification

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I received the notification so I handle it like so

```
-(void) dateSelected:(NSNotification *) notification
{
NSLog(@"Value: %@", [[notification userInfo] valueForKey:@"date"] );
NSMutableDictionary * dateDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[notification userInfo]];
NSLog(@"The Date Dict: %@", dateDict );
}
```

The logs I get are

```
2012-07-20 11:32: TestApp[10701:40b] Value: (null)
2012-07-20 11:32: TestApp[10428:40b] The Date Dict: {
}
```

If I NSLog out the notification itself it looks valid:

```
2012-07-20 11:33: TestApp[10457:40b] Notification: NSConcreteNotification 0x16629460 {name = date_selected_; object = {
date = 20120705;
}}
```

I've done this before and its worked.

I'm sure its simple, but today I cannot see the issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
-Code

Comment: are you sure that the date-object is not nil and that it is passed correctly to the userInfo dictionary. maybe u can post the code where you create and append the data object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty simple, look at your log output ... There's no *userInfo* set in your notification. There's just *name* and *object*. Compare your output with this one ...

```
NSNotification *notification = [NSNotification notificationWithName:@"NAME"
  object:self
  userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"obj", @"key", nil]];
NSLog( @"NOT: %@", notification );
```

...

```
NOT: NSConcreteNotification 0x73586f0 {name = NAME;
object = <CMAppDelegate: 0x884a4e0>; userInfo = {
    key = obj;
}}
```

... see the difference? There's *name*, *object*, but also *userInfo* in log output.

So the answer is - your notification does not contain *userInfo* dictionary. Look at code which fires this notification.